# Intercept hard keypress in android with asynctask

Tags: android, button, controller, android-asynctask, key

I recently purchased an 8-bitty iCade controller from Think Geek for gaming, unfortunately this controller is nearly useless because of the design. It enumerates as a HID keyboard but the flaw is that there are two key codes for every button and no key repeat:

- w/e = Up down/up
- x/z = Down down/up
- a/q = Left down/up
- d/c = Right down/up
- y/t = Select down/up
- u/f = Start down/up
- k/p = B down/up
- l/v = A down/up
- i/m = X down/up
- o/g = Y down/up
- h/r = L down/up
- j/n = R down/up

With the combination of different key codes for the same button and no key repeat there's no way to use this as a native gamepad in android. I have tried to use the Softkeyboard sample app in the SDK to intercept hardware key events but have not been successful past getting it to keyupdown the button forever and my phone locking up and rebooting.

To deal with the rebooting I attempted to use asynctask but I can't do

```
while (keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Q){
     keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A);
}
```

in doinbackground because keyCode is undefined.

How should/can this be accomplished?